# Update libstdc++.so.6 without updating gcc? Rhel 6.7

Tags: gcc, libstdc++, rhel6

I'm trying to install a package that requires GLIBCXX_3.4.20. GCC version is 4.4, the highest version yum lists. Is there a way to upgrade to 4.9 without building it from source or just update libstdc++?

Answer (score 0):

you probably could just grab a recent [Fedora libstdc++ rpm](http://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/fedora/linux/releases/24/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/l/libstdc++-6.1.1-2.fc24.x86_64.rpm), unpack it using something like [`rpm2targz`](https://gitweb.gentoo.org/proj/rpm2targz.git/), and then move the two shared libs into `/usr/local/lib/`, then run `ldconfig`.

you might need to adjust the rpm (x86_64-vs-i686) and lib-vs-lib64 paths depending on your setup.

using a newer libstdc++.so with an older gcc version shouldn't *usually* be too much of a problem.  they're good about backwards compat support in the shared libs.